# How can I get CMake to allow for "make clean"ing just one target?

Tags: makefile, build, cmake, resource-cleanup

I have a project using CMake to generate Makefiles, which then get built with (GNU) make.

In my project, the `CMakeLists.txt` defines two targets - but only one of them gets built when `make`ing after `Makefile` generation (e.g. using the `EXCLUDE_FROM_DEFAULT_BUILD` property).

I want to be able to cleanup (using `make`) the files used in the building of one of the targets, but not the files used to build the second target.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I see two additional options:

1. Using the internal `cmake_clean.cmake` scripts generated for for each target - which, unfortunately, are not directly accessible through `make` from the root path. For example, if you have a target named `foo`, you would write:

   ```
    cmake -P CMakeFiles/foo.dir/cmake_clean.cmake
   ```
2. Using [`ninja`](https://ninja-build.org/manual.html#_extra_tools) instead of `make` generators where you could call

   ```
    ninja -t clean foo
   ```

Comment: Re *"the internally for each target generated"*: do you mean *"the internally generated for each target"*? And what does *"internally"* and *"generated"* refer to (one or more nouns missing)? - what is it that is internal and generated?

Comment: Unfortunately this will also clean any targets which foo depends on.
Is there a way to clean only foo ?